# Selenium chrome window appear on top and interrupts when closed or click cause open new tab

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Its been very irritating that whenever some ads opened up, I switch all windows and close ads window, but `driver.close()` pop selenium window on top of all my windows, and if on new desktop it changes desktop and again pop (windows 10).

Me doing some gaming while running selenium tests, but it minimized my game window and show me selenium window when click on button causes new tab to open or `driver.close` method is called

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `Me doing some gaming while running selenium tests, but it minimized my game window and show me selenium window` .. Going by this sentence, if you do not want the selenium window to open up on your activity, you may try `headless` mode, in which the window does not open at all..

Comment: No, headless got easily detected and banned from websites, other suggestion

Comment: @FaucetCrypto What website is this? Can you share your code?

Comment: For all, you can use any, just use driver.switch_to.window and see this